# Transparency and GIF in .NET -- Inconsistent behavior

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, transparency, gif

I am trying to edit and save an image using the .net Bitmap class. Some of the pixels are transparent, and they get converted to black under certain circumstances. If I save the same image like this:

```
image.Save("copy1.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
image.Save("copy2.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
image.Save("copy3.gif");
```

(Image being originally a gif) the first and third are correct retaining the transparency, but the middle one sets all the transparent pixels to black. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, AFAIK the last two lines should be equivalent.

Here is a sample program of what I am talking about:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Net;

namespace TestGif
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(WebRequest.Create(
                "http://rlis.com/images/column/ie_icon.gif")
                           .GetResponse()
                           .GetResponseStream());

            int width = bitmap.Width;
            int height = bitmap.Height;
            Bitmap copy = new Bitmap(width, height);
            var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(copy);
            graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, new Point(0, 0));
            copy.Save("copy1.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            copy.Save("copy2.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
            copy.Save("copy3.gif");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To verify if the last 2 lines of code are the same (the Save calls) do copy2.gif and copy3.gif come out as identical files?  Or are they different?  My guess is that the extension isn't enough to tip off the Save method as to the ImageFormat you want.

Comment: The third Save() call actually saves a PNG.  Which doesn't fool any program, they'll look at the file header instead of the filename extension.  Something wrong with your GIF reader, I'd guess.

Comment: I tried to add the images to the question, but to no avail. copy2.gif is not identical to copy3.gif. However as the second commenter points out it does look like it is just the PNG file saved under a different name. That explains something, but not why the gif substitutes black for the transparent pixels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last line

```
copy.Save("copy3.gif");
```

does not save as gif file, but as png, since the extension is not sufficient to specify the saving format.
To make a transparent gif, use something like

```
Color c = copy.GetPixel(0, 0);
copy.MakeTransparent(c);
```

Your code is creating a new bitmap, possibly losing the original gif informations.

Comment: Thanks Michele, that hits the nail on the head.